# Is possible to capture packets between two hosts from a third host in the same network?

Tags: tcpdump

I want to see traffic between two hosts from a third host, there are all on my network
I did this on the third host:

```
ip link set eth0 promisc on

tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -xX host 192.168.0.2 and host 192.168.0.38 and not stp
```

I did ssh on 192.168.0.2, from 192.168.0.2 I ping 192.168.0.38 and instead of see the udp datagrams on my terminal I see this

```
tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -xX host 192.168.0.2 and host 192.168.0.38 and not stp
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
8 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Why?

I try to specify src and dst..

```
  tcpdump -vv -i eth0 -xX src host 192.168.0.2 and dst host 192.168.0.38 and not stp
```

but nothing change.

Comment: try to find an ethernet hub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say, "... on my network ..."

If you have access to the physical network layer, then yes, it is possible.

Some managed switches have the ability to copy traffic destined for port X to Port Y.

Another possibility, if the `tcpdump` host has multiple NICs, is to put the `tcpdump` host in between the other two hosts and let it bridge the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found probably.
The syntax is correct, but modern switched networks (unlike the older with shared bus like the old good 10base2 or base5) don't send traffic out the switch port
not connected to the destination MAC address, so tcpdump will show packets only from host connected directly.

Comment: Which is why you need physical access, and either configure your switch to broadcast or use a hub instead, or change the networking topology and use the snooping device as a switch etc.